# Web App Error After Installing Java on Centos Server

Tags: tomcat, web, centos, runtime-error, jakarta-mail

Good day.

My web app is programmed in jsp, using some of jQuery and javascript, is on a server with Centos 6.4, the app run its own java 1.7.0 - tomcat 8.0.21 and between its functions, uses javax.mail library which in a normal day can send from 5 to 50 messages.

As the server does not have native java and i need to run some jars on it, i installed java 1.7.0 using **yum install** to the server that does not have any conflict with the app's java on the start and/or execution.

The app starts normally and almost everything is ok, but after the installation of the server's java, i got **javax.mail.messagingexception[eof]** when my app is trying to send a mail through gmail smtp.

My immediate idea was to remove the server's java using **yum remove** and reboot the system but, the issue persists.

I tried to update google's certificates, verify the config of smtp and the authentication from centos console but everything seems to be ok, even i am able to send a mail from the centos console without any error or exception, but not from the app.

i where searching for almost 2 weeks including every reference to the javax.mail exception and there is no clue why the java installation could produce the malfunction.

i have no more info or exception code because the app was programmed like this and i cannot access to the font-code, the app log only prints javax.mail.messagingexception[eof] .

Anyone knows how the java installation can produce this?

There is temp-files or something that could remains on centos after uninstall that can produce this?

Sorry for the length, i had to provide as much details as posible due to the nature and conditions of the situation.

Thanks for your time, regards.

Comment: **SOLVED** **12/04/2016** **:** The issue was solved by tracing the EHLO hostname sent to gmail through smtp, which were incomplete so, the parameter was modified with the server's fullname. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED 12/04/2016** : The issue was solved by tracing the EHLO hostname sent to gmail through smtp, which were incomplete so, the parameter was modified with the server's fullname. Thanks for your time. –

Answer (score 0):

Without the ability to debug the program you'll probably have to use some network level debugging tool such as tcpdump to see what's happing on the connection when this error occurs.  Most likely this error indicates that the connection has been closed or dropped, but it's impossible to guess why.  A good place to start would be to make sure you don't have a firewall or anti-virus that's preventing the application from connecting to Gmail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BillShannon, i'd never use tcpdump before so i'm gonna try. About the firewall the support team of the host ensure that everything it's ok and the server has no anti-virus. I will update any progress.